# Retrieve Realm Object by Primary Key fails on iOS with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm, swift3

I recently upgraded my iOS Project to Swift 3 and iOS 10. Since then I'm running into a weird problem with Realm.

Here is what I try to do: I have a set of Positions, which I want to update with Server Data. So for every existing Position, I want to update it if there exists a newer version. If there is a Server Position, which doesn't exist locally, then I add it.

Here is the Code for that:

```
let newPositions = serializePositions(jsonResponse)
for newPosition in newPositions {
    if let existingPositon = uiRealm.object(ofType: Position.self, forPrimaryKey: newPosition.id as String) {
        if (progress.learningVersion < serverLearningVersion) {
            try! uiRealm.write {
                existingPositon.rank = newPosition.rank
                existingPositon.starred = newPosition.starred
            }
        }
    } else {
        try! uiRealm.write {
            progress.positions.append(newPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this, the something weird happens:

For the firstItem in the loop (the first Position) it works correctly. 
But then for the following Positions I get nil for existing Positions, even if it exists.

The Primary Key in the Position Model is a String Field and I use MongoDB Object Ids from the Server.

This is how the Positions are serialized from JSON:

```
func serializePositions(_ json: JSON) -> List<Position> {
    let positions = List<Position>()
    let serverPositions = json["positions"].arrayValue
    for serverPosition in serverPosition {
        let position = Position()
        position.id = listItem["id"].stringValue
        position.starred = listItem["starred"].boolValue
        position.rank = listItem["version"].intValue
        positions.append(position)
    }
    return positions
}
```

I'm pretty new to Realm and iOS and I hope, that I just make a stupid little mistake here. Thanks in advance for every idea..

Cheers, 
Raffi

Comment: Could you please share the JSON input and the previous state of the Realm. Without the inputs, it's hard to diagnose why you're not getting the output you're hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. I simply closed a for loop at the wrong position. As the issue was not related to Realm or JSON in the end I don't post the changes. Really it dosnt't help nobody :)